# Maintain shortest paths while updating graph

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory

I want to know the distance between all pairs (ex. dijkstra. Specifically I'm using networkx)
Then when an edge is added to graph I want to update the distances without recomputing from scratch.

How can this be done? 
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It is possible without recomputing all shortest paths but still pretty costly `O(n^2)`.

So lets assume you have a distance matrix `M` with size n*n where each entry `M_{i,j}` contains the distance from node `i` to node `j`. M is assumed to be precalculated by some algorithm.

Now if a new edge `e_{i,j}` is added to the graph between node `i` and node `j` with cost `w_{i,j}`, you check if `w_{i,j} < M_{i,j}`. If not, then nothing has to be changed. But if it holds, then the shortest paths in the graph might improve.

Then for each node pair `k, l` you check if the path going through the new edge is shorter than the previously calculated one. This can be done by evaluating the following.

```
M_{k,l} > min (M_{k,i} + w_{i,j} + M_{j,l} , M_{k,j} + w_{j,i} + M_{i,l})
```

If this holds then you can replace `M_{k,l}` by `min (M_{k,i} + w_{i,j} + M_{j,l} , M_{k,j} + w_{j,i} + M_{i,l})`

The above works for unidirectional graphs but can be adapted to bi-directional graphs as well.

**Edit 1**

I firmly believe that \Omega(n^2) is also the lower bound of this problem. Assume you have two disconnected areas of the graph both containing n/2 vertices. Then if you add a new edge connecting these areas you will have to update n/2 * n/2 shortest paths resulting in at least O(n^2) runtime.

**Edit 2**

A second idea would try to exploit the above equation but run through the graph first in order to find all pairs of vertices that have to be updated first. The sketch of the idea is as follows:

Start a Dijkstra from node i. Whenever you reach a vertex k you check if `M_{k, i} + w_{i, j} <  M_{k, j}` if yes then add k to the set U of vertices that have to be updated. If not, then you can stop exploring further paths following k, since no vertex "beyond" k will use e_{i, j} for the shortest path.

Then do the same for node j. And then perform the update of M for all pairs of vertices in U according to the ideas above.

Comment: That could work and although its 0(N^2). Dijksra could be O(ElogV) depending on implementations. I think the worst case is similar to dijkstra since it could affect all pairs. However, I'm thinking of something that would "ripple" the update the neighbors as needed and hopefully will stop at O(1) for most updates

Comment: @user2232888 The runtime of O(V log V +E) for Dijkstra only computes the single source shortest path. As I understood your question you want all pairs shortest path to be updated. Floyd-Warshall will take O(n^3) for that.

Comment: Thanks, I think that depending on the magnitude of the change, sometimes the change will be large and run O like all_pairs. But sometime the change is small and won't affect most pairs. then the runtime should be O(1)
For now I've changed my algorithm to avoid this type of compute everytime the graph is changed. If performance is not as good I'll come back to it in a couple of weeks

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible in O(V log(v) [which is for the priority queue] + E [bc. you cannot know what new edges the algorithm will take])